# Sensor shape must match. ml-agents, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reinforcement-learning, ml-agent

I am using unity and ml-agents, and have started modifying this project: https://github.com/CoderOneHQ/ultimate-volleyball

I have a added more observations to my agents, where it used to have 11 observations and now i added 7 more. The observations i tried adding was positioning of a second player (teammate). here are my the observations section of my code:

```
public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
{
    // Agent rotation (1 float)
    sensor.AddObservation(this.transform.rotation.y);

    // Vector from agent to ball (direction to ball) (3 floats)
    Vector3 toBall = new Vector3((ballRb.transform.position.x - this.transform.position.x)*agentRot, 
    (ballRb.transform.position.y - this.transform.position.y),
    (ballRb.transform.position.z - this.transform.position.z)*agentRot);

    sensor.AddObservation(toBall.normalized);

    // Distance from the ball (1 float)
    sensor.AddObservation(toBall.magnitude);

    // Agent velocity (3 floats)
    sensor.AddObservation(agentRb.velocity);

    // Ball velocity (3 floats)
    sensor.AddObservation(ballRb.velocity.y);
    sensor.AddObservation(ballRb.velocity.z*agentRot);
    sensor.AddObservation(ballRb.velocity.x*agentRot);

    // Vector from agent to teammate (direction to teammate) (3 floats)
    Vector3 toMate = new Vector3((mateRb.transform.position.x - this.transform.position.x)*agentRot, 
    (mateRb.transform.position.y - this.transform.position.y),
    (mateRb.transform.position.z - this.transform.position.z)*agentRot);

    sensor.AddObservation(toMate.normalized);

    // Distance from the mate (1 float)
    sensor.AddObservation(toMate.magnitude);

    // Mate velocity (3 floats)
    sensor.AddObservation(mateRb.velocity.y);
    sensor.AddObservation(mateRb.velocity.z*agentRot);
    sensor.AddObservation(mateRb.velocity.x*agentRot);

    
}
```

When i run unity i now get one error and one warning at the same time, the error and warning are given in the following line respectivly:

```
Sensor shapes must match. [18] != [11]
UnityEngine.Debug:AssertFormat (bool,string,object[])
Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.SensorShapeValidator:ValidateSensors (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ISensor>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Sensors/SensorShapeValidator.cs:43)
Unity.MLAgents.RpcCommunicator:PutObservations (string,Unity.MLAgents.AgentInfo,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ISensor>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Communicator/RpcCommunicator.cs:319)
Unity.MLAgents.Policies.RemotePolicy:RequestDecision (Unity.MLAgents.AgentInfo,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ISensor>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Policies/RemotePolicy.cs:46)
Unity.MLAgents.Agent:SendInfoToBrain () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Agent.cs:1096)
Unity.MLAgents.Agent:SendInfo () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Agent.cs:1323)
Unity.MLAgents.Academy:EnvironmentStep () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Academy.cs:573)
Unity.MLAgents.AcademyFixedUpdateStepper:FixedUpdate () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Academy.cs:43)

More observations (18) made than vector observation size (11). The observations will be truncated.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarningFormat (string,object[])
Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.VectorSensor:Write (Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ObservationWriter) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Sensors/VectorSensor.cs:47)
Unity.MLAgents.GrpcExtensions:GetObservationProto (Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ISensor,Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ObservationWriter) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Communicator/GrpcExtensions.cs:399)
Unity.MLAgents.RpcCommunicator:PutObservations (string,Unity.MLAgents.AgentInfo,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ISensor>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Communicator/RpcCommunicator.cs:330)
Unity.MLAgents.Policies.RemotePolicy:RequestDecision (Unity.MLAgents.AgentInfo,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ISensor>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Policies/RemotePolicy.cs:46)
Unity.MLAgents.Agent:SendInfoToBrain () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Agent.cs:1096)
Unity.MLAgents.Agent:SendInfo () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Agent.cs:1323)
Unity.MLAgents.Academy:EnvironmentStep () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Academy.cs:573)
Unity.MLAgents.AcademyFixedUpdateStepper:FixedUpdate () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.1.0-exp.1/Runtime/Academy.cs:43)
```

How can i fix this?